# строки. оператор повторения(repetition operator)

Tags: perl

Есть две инструкции:

`print "o" . "la" x 4 * 3, "\n";`

`print "ba" ."na" x4*3,"\n";`

Если в первом случае вывод очевиден: `o0`, то почему во второй инструкции вывод будет `baNaN`, а не `ba0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Операция умножения требует конвертации строки в число, но строка начинающаяся с `nan` (регистр не важен), интерпретируется как числовое значение `NaN` (не число)

```perl
say int "nanomachines" # NaN
```

Так же как, например, строка начинающаяся с `inf`, интерпретируется как `Inf` (+∞)

```perl
say -int "information" # -Inf
```

В вашем случае

```perl
say int "na" x 4 # NaN
```

потому, что `int "nananana"` возвращает специальное числовое значение

```perl
say int "la" x 4 # 0
```

потому, что `int "lalalala"` просто считает, что строка не содержит ведущих цифр, и возвращает 0